# Encode # in URL with json

Tags: json, url, encoding

I have the following call to my webservice:

```
http://xxx/GetTrackerData/{"KundenNr":"1111","Domain":"SuppKdNr036373#0001","Datum":"20.10.2015","AuftrNr":"2015018"}
```

On server-side, I get the following value for the parameters:

```
{"KundenNr":"1111","Domain":"SuppKdNr036373
```

The value is cut off as soon as a # is included in one of the JSON values. Can anyone tell me, how to encode the # correctly?

I've tried %23, but this doesn't work. Any help would be great.

Comment: What are you running this in/from? You are url encoding that `{..}` string, right?

Comment: Why doesn't %23 work?

Comment: Tried with Postman and Chrome.
%23 leads to same result as # on server side (cut off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. I don't have to encode it once, I need to do it twice.

Encoding #

Once: %23

Twice: %2523

This lead me to the solution: [Percent-encode URL Twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112447/percent-encode-url-twice)

With encoding twice, special chars are correctly sent to server and interpreted by webservice.